# What character encoding is this? and how can I decode it?

Tags: sql-server, database, encoding, fonts, character-encoding

i have a sqlserver database stored as base64 encoding, like this.

```
first name 

AeS55lS/I4xV1+jSkwT/7g==
9Y2XLwJB0C4BoDD2ImuTDY4ikxV1mxqXSNR/M6CE8Y0=
uiqUcbxTY2LhKFzGC4Ym8J1yHkaaO5uj1/xIUuMMSBI=
0mjkeHgZonVklkNjbreYoThsqU+4iGPSDIQN+XTFvys=
AeS55lS/I4xV1+jSkwT/7g==
XvglRYMFbOvEfI/iWcUJoGLjN5A7+gzVCmFJQSiyMyQ=
XvglRYMFbOvEfI/iWcUJoGkdOOBYt6JjQEb7Kt8ynQA=
```

when i decode base64 to strings i get:

```
ä¹æT¿#ŒU×èÒ“ÿî
õ—/AÐ. 0ö"k“ Ž"“u›—HÔ3 „ñ
º*”q¼Scbá(\Æ†&ðrFš;›£×üHRãH
Òhäxx¢ud–Ccn·˜¡8l©O¸ˆcÒ„ ùtÅ¿+
ä¹æT¿#ŒU×èÒ“ÿî
^ø%EƒlëÄ|âYÅ    bã7;úÕ aIA(²3$
^ø%EƒlëÄ|âYÅ    i8àX·¢c@Fû*ß2
```

i havd tried migrated database to mysql and change to utf-8 but still showing same encoded text, I had tried with various encoding detector(chardet, some python script from github, file) also tried encoding converter like iconv but still no luck, i am searching it from last 3 days.

what encoding is this?

how to decode it to proper language?

sqlserver collation is sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as.

Comment: If you don't know what encoding it is you don't know for good reason; because you shouldn't be able to decode it.

Comment: @Larnu maybe you could expand on your comment? - as it stands, it sounds a bit condescending to the OP and outside of the 'Be Nice' guidelines.  Remember that somethings are obvious to you but not necessarily to others.  Care to rephrase?

Comment: Effectively: if you don't know what the decoded data is supposed to be, _ask the people who wrote the code that added it into the database to begin with_. Don't ask Stackoverflow, ask the people whose code you are clearly working with. They are the _only_ people who can tell you exactly what is going on here. We are not part of that journey of discovery.

Comment: People here learn from own experiences, if I did some mistake then you can correct me.

Comment: The point t people are making here is that encoding is something that intentionally makes something unreadable apart from by those that know the algorithm, and key, to decode it. If you don't know the algorithm, or key, then the likelihood is that you shouldn't be able access the data; that why ity encoded to you. If you *do* need it decoded, asking strangers on the internet isn't the right place; you need to talk to whoever encoded it and get them to assist you. On the other hand, if it's something you encoded and forgot how (and lost the key), you don't really have any options I'm afraid.

Comment: i don't encoded it, but my service provider, now i am unable to contact him, i have all databse including master database.

Comment: SQL doesn't have the ability to encrypt only backups, that was added in SQL 2014. is_encrypted in sys.databases indicates whether Transparent Database Encryption is enabled for the database. so this is not encrypted it is encoded

Comment: @Lamu You are confusing _encoding_ with _encryption_. No "key" is used with encoding, and there is no "algorithm"; a given encoding just implements a formally documented mapping. While the purpose of encryption is to make data unreadable to unauthorized users, that is not the purpose of encoding at all. Lack of knowledge of an encoding being used does not automatically imply that the user is not entitled to know the encoding. Encoded data is not secure at all, and that is not its purpose.